# Express js related articles - error cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, express

I try to show related articles based on categories. I use mongoose to query things from MongoDB.

When I try the code below, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'category')" but console.log from articlecategories first showing array with categories and then throw the error "cannot read"..

I'm a beginner in express js, maybe someone gives me a hint.

```
 exports.articleDetail = async (req, res) => {
        const article = await Article.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate('category').populate('author');
        const articlecategories = article.category
        categories = []
        for(let i=0;i<articlecategories.length;i++){
          const category = articlecategories[i]
    
          categories.push(category._id)
        }
        console.log(categories)
        const relatedarticles = await Article.find({ category : { $all : categories }})
        console.log(article);
        res.render('article', { article, relatedarticles })
    }
```

**Edit**

Thank You all for answers. I have a solution. Problem is that when loop through article categories, I get no category ID but new ObjectId: **new ObjectId("636bc1c64f7470f2557b61d7")**

To let this work, I must use **.toString()** and get only Id and then push this Id to array.

**This is working code:**

```
 exports.articleDetail = async (req, res) => {
    const article = await Article.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate('category').populate('author');

    categories = []
    for(let i=0;i<article.category.length;i++){
      const category = article.category[i]

      const catid = category._id.toString()
  
      categories.push(catid)
    }

    console.log(categories)

    const articles = await Article.find({category: { $all: categories }}).populate('author')

    res.render('article', { article, articles })
}
```

Comment: Likely one of these `articlecategories[i]` is returning null, so you will want to check for this.

Comment: `const article` is set to null so in the next line you cant read category of null

Answer (score 0):

Probably your call to `await Article.findOne` just returns null since the object could not be found.

You should check if there is anything found and, if not, directly return an error like this:

```
exports.articleDetail = async (req, res) => {
        const article = await Article.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate('category').populate('author');
        if ( !article ) return res.status(404).json(/* include your error object here */);
        const articlecategories = article.category
        categories = []
        for(let i=0;i<articlecategories.length;i++){
          const category = articlecategories[i]
    
          categories.push(category._id)
        }
        console.log(categories)
        const relatedarticles = await Article.find({ category : { $all : categories }})
        console.log(article);
        res.render('article', { article, relatedarticles })
    }
```